# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MvxSock.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm trying to use the M3 API Toolkit for the first time and following the instructions at [here](http://m3ideas.org/2012/02/23/how-to-call-m3-api-from-net/)

I'm getting the following exception in my project.  I have **version 9.0.4.0** according to the readme file of the zip package

When I use the MvxSockN.dll I get the following error:-

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred
>   in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'MvxSock.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

And same error but for `MvxSockx64.dll` when I use the `MvxSockN64.dll`.

This seems to be a wrapper class written for .NET which using the `MvcSock.dll` file and therefore has a dependency on it. But how I can fix this since I am unable to add that as a reference. When I try to add the `MvxSock.dll` as reference it fails with this message:

> A reference to '...\MvxSock.dll' could not be added. Please make sure
>   that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM
>   component.

After adding all the contents on MvxAPI folder, I get the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
>
> Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

In addition to that I have also tried different .NET frameworks. 2.0, 4.5.2. Doesn't make any difference.

Any tips on how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks,

Comment: you need to put the dll in your path or in the same dir as your app binary

Comment: @pm100 Thanks, I have done that too. I have tried changing the applications .net framework to 2.0 from 4.5.2. Didnt work unfortunately

Comment: @pm100 short update there. Please check the question

Comment: use procmon from sysinternals to see where yr app is looking for the dlls. You will see it trying various paths and missing, put it in one of the places it is looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I solved the problem by

- Initially I didn't install the API Toolkit. I was given the installed folder to copy on my machine. So I installed M3 API Toolkit from the exe installer instead.
- Making my WCF application target 64bit platform.
- Adding the 64 bit DLLs into the \Bin AND all the 5 dlls in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folders.

These are the DLLs in SysWow64 folder:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A.K, yes, you have to install the M3 API Toolkit from its EXE installer (not simply unzipping from the ZIP) in order to register the DLLs on your system. Otherwise, if you simply unzip, you have to register the DLLs manually with the regsvr32 command; see the M3 API Toolkit documentation that explains it. Also, yes, you need to match the 32/64bit of your target architecture. --Thibaud